# Mysql delete a row php

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I have a MySQL table and i would like to delete a row in my table and after deleting the row the result must show all data left in my table .

```
<?php 
        include 'Connection.php';

        // Create connection 
        $con= mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
        if ($con->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
        } 

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM productos";
        $result = $con->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows >0) {
            while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
         $tem = $row;
         $json = json_encode(array("productos"=>$tem));
            } 
        } else { 
            echo "No Results Found.";
        }

        echo $json;
        $con->close();
?>
```

This is my select code... now i don't know how create the delete function..

Any help please.

Comment: `DELETE from XXX WHERE yyyy=Q` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: Thank you @rtfm for your help .. i already tried its work but he did'nt show me the json result

Comment: you need to call the select query you can do this by putting your select query into a function and then after deleting you can recall that function I hope it will work!

Answer (score 0):

You are  overwritting, make array of rows and then echo json_encode at last

```
 $items = array();
 if ($result->num_rows >0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
       $items[] = $row;
  } 
} else { 
  echo "No Results Found.";
}
echo json_encode(array("productos"=>$items));
$con->close();
```

Comment: thank you @user2486 now how create the delete function by id..cause i don't manage php.. please

Comment: Just make a function and paas `id` to delete like this `$sql = "DELETE FROM productos WHERE id=1";
        $result = $con->query($sql);`